# How to match any string before the nearest specific character?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match any characters before the **first** encountered specific character. Tried:

```
use feature 'say';
say $1 if 'bla-bla if (func(arg1, arg2) < 0) {' =~ /func\s*\((.*?)\)\s*\{/;
```

I assumed that there will be no output for this code, cause the `.*?` matches `arg1, arg2` (i.e. before the nearest `)` ) and there is no `{` after `func(arg1, arg2)` so the regex turns to false. However, the output was `arg1, arg2) < 0`. [Indeed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html), **non-greedy regex chooses as few as needed to allow the overall pattern to match**. But I want this regex to be false with such strings. I found in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598946/why-does-my-non-greedy-perl-regex-still-match-too-much) the working solution. In my case the `.*?` should be changed to `[^\)]*`. But is there any other ways to do it? Thanks for any clarifications and examples. Sorry if this is obvious

Comment: To clarify, you want to capture `arg1, arg2` instead of `arg1, arg2) < 0`, correct?

Comment: Hang on, so you have a good solution?  Are you asking simply whether there are yet other ways?

Comment: I don't want to capture. >I want this regex to be false with such strings

Comment: @zdim I have no other solutions, so I would be grateful for any examples

Comment: "I want this regex to be false with such strings" So you want to write a regex that *doesn't* match `bla-bla if (func(arg1, arg2) < 0) {`? In that case, what *do* you want to match?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I want to match strings like `func (...) {}` but not others

Comment: Your question states that you _do get_ that using `[^)]` ... ?  Am I misunderstanding it?  (Btw, that is the first thing I reach for when I need a non-greedy match.)

Comment: Help me out here, I don't understand.  Try this: `perl -wE '$str = "(func(arg1, arg2) < 0) {";  if ($str =~ m/func\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*\{/) { say "Got: $1" } else { say "nope" }'`.  I get `nope` as it stands, meaning that the match fails.  If I remove the  " < 0)" part then I get `arg1, arg2`.  Remove the capturing parenthesis if you don't need to remember the match itself.

Comment: Thanks @zdim. It seems to me that there is another way to specify my regex. But `[^)]` suits me of course. I don't need to capture something, it's just for example

Comment: Ah, OK.  The `[^char]` is my preferred way to do non-greedy matching.  Taken together with `.*?` (and friends) there is no reason to ask for yet another, in my opinion.  I think that there are no other idioms (or simple ways) for that ... in regex.  I suppose you can use `split` instead, where you get that for free.

Comment: @zdim Thanks for your clarification. Noted.

Comment: @red0ct: Why have you tagged "lookaround"? There are none here.

Comment: @Toto You're right. Inattentively read, sorry.